# azure connection string c#

Tags: c#, mysql, azure

I am trying to open connection with Azure SQL database. Tried creating usual `connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=" + server + "Database=" + database + "Uid=" + uid + "Password=" + password);` with every string variable ending with ; but yet it always fails to connect even if the data is correct. Tried to use given string for ADO.NET but then I am getting exception "keyword is not supported". I don't what else to actually.. Googled as much as possible but all solutions are quite the same and yet nothing works out for me :/

Comment: well, azure isn't mysql. Go figure.

Comment: What kind of database are you running in Azure? Are you sure it is mysql?

Comment: ohh I am sorry.. I am very new to databases

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, azure databases don't use mysql. so using `MySqlConnection()` won't work.

instead use

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
```

Standard connection strings should be in the format

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/ for more options

Answer (score 1):

```
var connectionString = @"Server=tcp:<dbname>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
```

That's how I connect to my Azure SQL Database, works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL In App you can use the fellowing code in c# to get the connection string:

```
    static string getConnectionString()
    {
    #if DEBUG
        string connectionString = "dbname=localdb;host=localhost:3306;user=root;pass=password;";
    #else
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb");
    #endif
        string[] options = connectionString.Split(";");
        string database = options[0].Split("=")[1]; ;
        string serverport = options[1].Split("=")[1];
        string server = serverport.Split(":")[0];
        string port = serverport.Split(":")[1];
        string user = options[2].Split("=")[1];
        string password = options[3].Split("=")[1]; ;

        connectionString = $"server={server};port={port};database={database};user={user};password={password};";

        return connectionString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard .Net Framework provider format is:

```
Server=[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

Azure SQL Database is an SQL Server type database, not MySQL!

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed Microsoft instructions?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio

You have to create server-level firewall rule on azure too, to be able to connect.